# Neo4j How to Merge Nodes from JSON Data when Key is optional

Tags: json, neo4j, cypher

So I have this JSON data that looks like:

```
{"title": "Title1", "authors": [{"name": "Dave Chappelle", "org": "MIT"}], "id": "abc123"}
{"title": "Title2", "authors": [{"name": "Rick Sanchez"}, {"name": "Amy Schumer"], "id": "xyz234"}
```

The `org` key is only present in some of the papers' author list.

When it is present, I would like to check if that organization already has a node. If the organization node does already exist, I just want to create the relationship if the relationship doesn't already exist. If the organization node doesn't exist, I want to create a node `(o:Organization {name:authors.org})` and create a relationship `WORKS_AT` between the author and the organization if the relationship doesn't already exist.

The query I'm currently trying:

```
CALL apoc.load.json('file.txt') YIELD value AS q UNWIND q.id AS id UNWIND q.authors as authors 
MERGE (a:Author {name:authors.name}) 
MERGE (o:Organization {name:authors.org}) WHERE authors.org IS NOT NULL 
MERGE (i:Paper {id:q.id}) ON CREATE SET i.title=q.title
MERGE (a)-[:WORKS_AT]->(o) 
RETURN o.name;
```

However, this gives me an error:

`Invalid input 'H': expected 'i/I' (line 2, column 109 (offset: 256))`

I think Cypher wants a `WITH` statement instead of a `WHERE`, but I'm not entirely sure why. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't know if it is the cause of your issue, but your sample CSV is invalid. You forgot a quotation mark in the first title (`{"title": "Title1`).

Comment: Thanks for catching that. My actual JSON file does not have this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to move where the condition is and add `WITH` like this:

`CALL apoc.load.json('file.txt') YIELD value AS q UNWIND q.id AS id UNWIND q.authors as authors
MERGE (a:Author {name:authors.name})
WITH a, q, authors
WHERE authors.org is not null
MERGE (o:Organization {name:authors.org}) 
MERGE (i:Paper {id:q.id}) ON CREATE SET i.title=q.title
MERGE (a)-[:WORKS_AT]->(o) 
RETURN o.name;`

The reason you're getting an error is that you're trying to do MERGE after WHERE, which isn't syntactically valid.  Write query structure in cypher works like this: (taken from [cypher refcard](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-refcard/current/))

`[MATCH WHERE]
[OPTIONAL MATCH WHERE]
[WITH [ORDER BY] [SKIP] [LIMIT]]
(CREATE [UNIQUE] | MERGE)*
[SET|DELETE|REMOVE|FOREACH]*
[RETURN [ORDER BY] [SKIP] [LIMIT]]`

After WHERE, there is no option to use MERGE without first using WITH.